# QGIS Color Ramp is not being displayed properly

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, color-ramp

I have QGIS **3.22.16** installed, as well as **QGIS 3.28.3**.

When I use QGIS **3.22.16**, only the color ramps I created are displayed accordingly. The other ones are missing the intermediary colors.
[image: screen capture showing color ramps not displayed as expected]

If i select to **edit color ramp**, I can see that the intermediary colours are set to *0% opacity*.

[image: Color ramp edition showing the issue]

I can edit all of them but It would take some time.
I tried to reinstall QGIS and nothing has worked.

I opened Qgis **3.28.3** and all color ramps are being properly displayed.

**QUESTION** 
Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this issue remains unsolved:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/51802

I discovered that this problem only occurs on notebooks. You need to adjust the opacity of the color ramp manually. Please see my screencast.

[qgis_color_ramp_issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uAV1vuRVrq9ZsTgZQGMLBcTOjWVod4XE/view?usp=sharing)